# Using AverageIF in Excel getting DIV/0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to take and average the salary of all females and males in a table, and I found another stack overflow article about this and tried to use the averageif formula, however whenever I try it gives me a $DIV/0 error, even though I do not think I'm dividing by zero anywhere in the range I set it. Here is a picture of the chart and the formula at the top in the formula bar[image]

Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula should be:

```
=AVERAGEIF(TABLE5[GENDER], "F", TABLE5[SALARY])
```

You parameters for AVERAGEIF are (CriteriaRange, Criteria, AverageRange).